# Should i make separate table for common database fields like active , createdAt etc

Tags: mysql, sql, database, data-modeling

IN my every database table , i have 5-6 feilds which are repetitive like

1. active
2. deleted
3. createdAt
4. updatedAt
5. updatedBy
6. createdBy

I am confused if i make separate tables for those or leave inside main table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<opinion>`I don't think it's be worth the extra hassle. Especially since the rows would never be shared by other rows - there will always be a 1-to-1 mapping between other rows and these rows. Just keep them in the tables where they are now. `</opinion>`

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, I will do the same as yours by put them in each table because you can't seperated the value. How do you know if active is refer to this, then the others is refer to this?

Thanks.
Regards,
Alfred

Comment: His proposed solution of moving these values into another table would certainly work. Lets call the table he has shown above "flags", and add a primary key. A table "articles" for example would have a foreign key "flag_id" that would point to a row in the "flags" table. Then you just JOIN on the two during your SELECT to get the data, as if it were all in one table.

Comment: or table `flags` can be named `content_edit_history` and have composite key `(content_type, id)`, where `content_type` is content table name

Comment: Also PostgreSQL supports table inheritance